# How can I get Journal entry data from Sitelink's web service(s)?

Tags: integration

I want to integrate my web site from the sitelink web edition. In my application, I want to maintain summary level accounting data for journal entry. After doing lot of investigation I came to know that there is no any web service available which can give you journal entry records from the Sitelink.
If some body has worked on it, please let me know, if there is any way to get these details?

Sitelink web services available:
https://www.smdservers.net/CCWs_3.5/ReportingWs.asmx

Thanks in advance,
Vagish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the webservice is available by sitelink in following location:
https://www.smdservers.net/CCWs_3.5/ReportingWs.asmx

Name of newly added webservice is "GeneralJournalEntries".